# How to add tag line just below of logo in yii framework navigation bar?

Tags: yii2

Here's my navigation bar menu code, I just want to place tagline below of my logo, how I do that.

```
NavBar::begin([
'brandLabel' => Html::img('pt_logo3.png'),
'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
'options' => [
'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
],
]);
```

[image]
In this image, i place tagline(The complete market intelligence solutions.)  in the logo but I need to place a text below the logo.

any help will be useful.

Comment: You mean and `<hr>`  tag ?

Comment: I need text below the logo.

Comment: then  explain better  ..  show a sample  ..

Comment: can't you just add a div with the text you want and place it under the logo using css?